# How to change width of line between nodes in tree diagram in D3.JS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I'm attempting to map survey data binary questions via D3.JS's tree diagram (specifically a version of Mike Bostock's collapsable tree diagram linked [here](https://codepen.io/inspirnathan/pen/BddJKB).

The idea here is that I want the width of the lines between nodes to be scaled based on the number of survey respondents who responded to that question answer (e.g. parent node = question 1, and "yes" responses equals child node 1, "no" responses equals child node 2, and the width of the lines between parent node and child nodes is equal to the proportion of the population that selected that response).

Any advice on how to set this up? Let me know if this makes sense -- see example data structure and basic tree below.

Thanks!

initial data structure looks like:

`{ "name": "Question", "children": [ {  "name": "Yes", }, { "name": "No" } ] };`

[Basic tree looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7yrI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The below illustrates how to adjust the stroke-width of your tree diagram example and should start you in the right direction.

Per the '[styling version](https://blocks.roadtolarissa.com/d3noob/08ecb6ea9bb68ba0d9a7e89f344acec8)' of your code example you could add a quality of stroke-width (here called thickness) to your data;

```
var treeData =
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "value": 10,
    "type": "black",
    "level": "red",
    "thickness": 2,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "value": 15,
        "type": "grey",
        "level": "red",
        "thickness": 4,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "value": 5,
            "type": "steelblue",
            "thickness": 6,
            "level": "orange"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "value": 8,
            "type": "steelblue",
            "thickness": 1,
            "level": "red"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "value": 10,
        "type": "grey",
        "thickness": 5,
        "level": "green"
      }
    ]
  };
```

And then call it into play when drawing the links;

```
var link = g.selectAll(".link")
    .data( nodes.descendants().slice(1))
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data.level; })
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.data.thickness; })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
       return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
         + "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.x
         + " " + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2 + "," + d.parent.x
         + " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
       });
```

Bearing in mind that I've repoduced the d3.js v4 example and you might consider moving to v7 ([updated example of the styling code](https://blocks.roadtolarissa.com/d3noob/1c7d618bd491abb1ebc1a0b5e05876fb)).

[image]

**Update:**
Here's the full code for the interactive example and with varying link thickness

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

</style>

<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>



var treeData = 
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "thickness": 4,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "thickness": 3,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "thickness": 2
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "thickness": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "thickness": 6
      }
    ]
  };



// Set the dimensions and margins of the diagram
var margin = {top: 20, right: 90, bottom: 30, left: 90},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

// declares a tree layout and assigns the size
var treemap = d3.tree().size([height, width]);

// Assigns parent, children, height, depth
root = d3.hierarchy(treeData, function(d) { return d.children; });
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// Collapse after the second level
root.children.forEach(collapse);

update(root);

// Collapse the node and all it's children
function collapse(d) {
  if(d.children) {
    d._children = d.children
    d._children.forEach(collapse)
    d.children = null
  }
}

function update(source) {

  // Assigns the x and y position for the nodes
  var treeData = treemap(root);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = treeData.descendants(),
      links = treeData.descendants().slice(1);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){ d.y = d.depth * 180});

  // ****************** Nodes section ***************************

  // Update the nodes...
  var node = svg.selectAll('g.node')
      .data(nodes, function(d) {return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new modes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on('click', click);

  // Add Circle for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('circle')
      .attr('class', 'node')
      .attr('r', 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) {
          return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
      });

  // Add labels for the nodes
  nodeEnter.append('text')
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
          return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });

  // UPDATE
  var nodeUpdate = nodeEnter.merge(node);

  // Transition to the proper position for the node
  nodeUpdate.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
     });

  // Update the node attributes and style
  nodeUpdate.select('circle.node')
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    })
    .attr('cursor', 'pointer');


  // Remove any exiting nodes
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
      })
      .remove();

  // On exit reduce the node circles size to 0
  nodeExit.select('circle')
    .attr('r', 1e-6);

  // On exit reduce the opacity of text labels
  nodeExit.select('text')
    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6);

  // ****************** links section ***************************

  // Update the links...
  var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  var linkEnter = link.enter().insert('path', "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.data.thickness; })
      .attr('d', function(d){
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      });

  // UPDATE
  var linkUpdate = linkEnter.merge(link);

  // Transition back to the parent element position
  linkUpdate.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d){ return diagonal(d, d.parent) });

  // Remove any exiting links
  var linkExit = link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y}
        return diagonal(o, o)
      })
      .remove();

  // Store the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d){
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

  // Creates a curved (diagonal) path from parent to the child nodes
  function diagonal(s, d) {

    path = `M ${s.y} ${s.x}
            C ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${s.x},
              ${(s.y + d.y) / 2} ${d.x},
              ${d.y} ${d.x}`

    return path
  }

  // Toggle children on click.
  function click(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    update(d);
  }
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @d3noob -- this is awesome -- thanks a bunch for the help. I've worked on this the last couple days but I haven't figured out how to properly embed you're `var link....` snippet in to the script.js code I linked in my original comment. Any advice on where I would embed this? I'm a bit confused and given I've spent a couple hours trying to solve this and failed thus far -- thought I would follow up and ask (as I have a feeling its something obvious). Cheers!

Comment: Following up: current way I've integrated your snippet above into the collapsable function ([here](https://codepen.io/inspirnathan/pen/BddJKB)) is like this: 
```// Update the links...

var link = svg.selectAll('path.link')
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.id; })
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.data.level; })
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.data.thickness; })

     ....```

Comment: Righto... What you appear to be missing in your [link above](https://codepen.io/inspirnathan/pen/BddJKB) is the addition of the 'thickness' values in your treedata json variable. In the answer above I have added `thickness` to the json and then called it out in the `var link = ` section

Comment: Hey apologies I'm following up as I should have uploaded a code snippet that was updated -- [see here](https://codepen.io/echar/pen/ExdXbxV). I didn't explain my error above well -- I did integrate the thickness piece into the tree but there's an issue with the collapsibility where the lines/paths do not collapse. Notice when you click the nodes to collapse the paths stay in place. I assumed the source of this was that I was integrating your thickness function in the wrong place but maybe its another issue?

Thank you so much for the help -- really (really) appreciate it.

Comment: Interesting! Without looking too close, I can't tell you what's going on there. However, I've addedd in the full code for the interactive example with the varying thickness links to the answer above. I suspect that something has gone amiss in the initial development of the code, and if you use this new example as a start point you should have more luck.